# Как переключаться между виджетами по кнопке Return/Enter?

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, qlineedit

Я хочу переключиться с `QLineEdit` на второй `QLineEdit`, 
после на `Qcombobox` и 
потом клик кнопки.

Все это должно происходить по кнопке `Return/Enter`.

Как это реализовать?

Comment: Опубликуйте пожалуйста пример, где присутствуют перечисленные вами виджеты. И ответьте пожалуйста, вас предыдущий вопрос решен или нет?

Comment: извините за отсутствие кода, варианты решения для предыдущего вопроса не подошли

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Плохая практика не публиковать минимальный пример демонстрирующий 
работу вашего приложения. 
Отсутствие обратной связи также не очень хорошо.

Учитывая, что ответ может быть полезен и другим членам сообщества,
я опубликую свой вариант ответа.
Если я правильно понял ваш вопрос, вы хотите пробежаться по виджетам
приложения нажимая клавишу **Return/Enter**.

**Первое**, что надо сделать, это установить **фокус** на виджет, с которого 
вы начинаете пробежку.

**Далее** по виджетам:

- сигнал `QLineEdit::returnPressed()`, испускается при нажатии клавиши Return или Enter.
- для `QComboBox` и `QPushButton` вам необходимо переопределить метод `keyPressEvent`.

Все, запускаем приложение, нажимаем четыре раза на клавишу Enter и смотрим результат.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class PushButton(QPushButton):
    keyPressButton = pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self, text, parent=None):
        super(PushButton, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setText(text)
        self.setStyleSheet("PushButton:focus {background-color: rgb(55, 155, 127);color:#fff}")

    def keyPressEvent(self, event): 
        if event.key() == Qt.Key_Return:     
            #self.test_method()
            self.keyPressButton.emit("Ok")
        super(PushButton, self).keyPressEvent(event)


class ComboBox(QComboBox):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ComboBox, self).__init__(parent)
        self.parent = parent

    def keyPressEvent(self, event): 
        if event.key() == Qt.Key_Return:     
            self.parent.buttonOk.setFocus()
        super(ComboBox, self).keyPressEvent(event)

class Dialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Dialog, self).__init__()
        self.createFormGroupBox()

        self.label = QLabel()

        self.buttonOk = PushButton("Ok", self) 
        self.buttonOk.keyPressButton.connect(self.onClickOk)

        self.buttonCancel = QPushButton("Cancel", autoDefault=False)   
        layoutH = QHBoxLayout()
        layoutH.addWidget(self.buttonOk)
        layoutH.addWidget(self.buttonCancel)

        self.mainLayout = QGridLayout()
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.formGroupBox, 0, 0, 1, 2)
        self.mainLayout.addLayout(layoutH, 1, 1, 1, 1, alignment=Qt.AlignRight)
        self.setLayout(self.mainLayout)

        self.setWindowTitle("Form Layout")
        self.lineEditName.setFocus()
        QTimer.singleShot(0, self.lineEditName.deselect)

    def createFormGroupBox(self):
        self.formGroupBox = QGroupBox("Form layout")
        self.comboBox = ComboBox(self) #QComboBox()
        self.comboBox.addItems(["Choose a Number", "1", "2", "3", "4"])
        self.comboBox.setCurrentIndex(2)
        self.lineEditName = QLineEdit("Вася Пупкин")
        self.lineEditEmail = QLineEdit("vasya@gmail.com")
        self.lineEditName.returnPressed.connect(self.lineEditEmail.setFocus)
        self.lineEditEmail.returnPressed.connect(self.comboBox.setFocus)
        layout = QFormLayout()
        layout.addRow(QLabel("Name:"),   self.lineEditName)
        layout.addRow(QLabel("email:"),  self.lineEditEmail)
        layout.addRow(QLabel("Country:"),self.comboBox)
        self.formGroupBox.setLayout(layout)

    def onClickOk(self, text):
        self.label.setText("{} -> {} -> {} -> {}".format(self.lineEditName.text(), 
                                                   self.lineEditEmail.text(), 
                                                   self.comboBox.currentText(),
                                                   text))
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.label, 2, 0, 1, 2)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    dialog = Dialog()
    sys.exit(dialog.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Используй маршрутизацию событий.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [справке](/help/how-to-answer).